# How to make the value of a StreamProvider.value widget dynamic

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.value widget which I use to provide the snapshots of a firebase query. In particularly, a specific card's snapshots as you can see down below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The rename function of a card goes likes this. The previous card's data are retrieved, the previous card is deleted and the new card is being set with the data of the previous card. Every time I try to rename a card from the app, the provider value turns into null because the previous document is deleted. Is there any way to make the value of the provider dynamic in order for the provider to take every time the value of the new renamed card?

Down below I share the code of the stream provider, cards name textfield and rename functionallity.

```
class EditListCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String thisSpecificBoardName;
  final String thisSpecificListName;
  final String thisSpecificCardName;
  final cardsIndex;

  EditListCard({
    this.thisSpecificCardName,
    this.thisSpecificListName,
    this.thisSpecificBoardName,
    this.cardsIndex,
  });

  @override
  State<EditListCard> createState() => _EditListCardState();
}

class _EditListCardState extends State<EditListCard> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    // print('xxx cardsName: ${Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).cardsName}');
    // Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).setName(widget.thisSpecificCardName);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Color(0xffEA8380)
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        ///For the card name
        //String temp = getCardName().toString();
        if (cardNameEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
          DatabaseServiceBoards()
              .renameCardName(widget.thisSpecificBoardName, widget.thisSpecificListName, 
widget.thisSpecificCardName, cardNameEditingController.text);
      cardNameEditingController.clear();
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    focusOfCardNameTextField.unfocus();
    cardDescriptionFocus.unfocus();
    addChecklistFocus.unfocus();
    editChecklistFocuses.forEach((element) {
      element.unfocus();
    });

    cardNameEditingController.clear();

    ///For add checklist textfield
    if (addNewChecklistTextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      DatabaseServiceBoards().addChecklistTile(
          widget.thisSpecificBoardName, widget.thisSpecificListName, widget.thisSpecificCardName, addNewChecklistTextEditingController.text);
      addNewChecklistTextEditingController.clear();
    }

    ///For the checklist tile textfield

    if (Provider.of<CardsChecklistDataProvider>(context, listen: false).checklistTileController != null) {
      if (Provider.of<CardsChecklistDataProvider>(context, listen: false).checklistTileController.text.isNotEmpty) {
        DatabaseServiceBoards().renameChecklistTile(
          widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
              widget.thisSpecificListName,
              widget.thisSpecificCardName,
              Provider.of<CardsChecklistDataProvider>(context, listen: false).checklistTileText,
              Provider.of<CardsChecklistDataProvider>(context, listen: 
false).checklistTileController.text,
            );
            //Provider.of<CardsChecklistDataProvider>(context, listen: 
false).checklistTileController.clear();
          }
        }
      },
      child: StreamProvider<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.value(
        initialData: null,
        value: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('boards')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .collection('boards')
            .doc(widget.thisSpecificBoardName)
            .collection('lists')
            .doc(widget.thisSpecificListName)
            .collection('cards')
            .doc(widget.thisSpecificCardName)
            .snapshots(),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              /// Header Bar
              //HeaderBar(),
              EditListCardHeader(
                thisSpecificBoardName: widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                thisSpecificCardName: widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                thisSpecificListName: widget.thisSpecificListName,
              ),

              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  children: [
                    /// Description TextField
                    CardDescription(
                      thisSpecificCardName: widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                      thisSpecificListName: widget.thisSpecificListName,
                      thisSpecificBoardName: widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10),

                    /// Fundamental Card Options

                    FundamentalCardOptions(
                      thisSpecificCardName: widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                      thisSpecificListName: widget.thisSpecificListName,
                      thisSpecificBoardName: widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10),

                    /// Checklist
                    ListCardChecklistBuilder(
                      thisSpecificCardName: widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                      thisSpecificListName: widget.thisSpecificListName,
                      thisSpecificBoardName: widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class EditListCardHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  final String thisSpecificCardName, thisSpecificBoardName;
  final String thisSpecificListName;

  final Function editBoardScreenSetStateCallback;

  EditListCardHeader({this.thisSpecificCardName, this.thisSpecificListName, 
this.thisSpecificBoardName, this.editBoardScreenSetStateCallback});

  @override
  _EditListCardHeaderState createState() => _EditListCardHeaderState();
}


class _EditListCardHeaderState extends State<EditListCardHeader> {
  var hintTextVar;
  String cardName;

  Widget backAndCrossWidget;
  Widget moreOptionsAndCheckWidget;

  /// This var is used to prevent a small bug in the sub-case where the user
  /// renames multiple times the same folder after he opens it.
  int renameCount = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    focusOfCardNameTextField.addListener(_onFocusChange);

    hintTextVar = widget.thisSpecificCardName;

    temp = widget.thisSpecificCardName;

    backAndCrossWidget = EditListCardBackIcon();
    moreOptionsAndCheckWidget = EditListCardMoreOptions(
      thisSpecificCardName: widget.thisSpecificCardName,
      thisSpecificListName: widget.thisSpecificListName,
      thisSpecificBoardName: widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
    );

    super.initState();
  }

  void _onFocusChange() {
    if (focusOfCardNameTextField.hasFocus == true) {
      if (renameCount == 0) {
        cardNameEditingController.text = widget.thisSpecificCardName;
      } else {
        cardNameEditingController.text = temp;
      }

      renameCount++;
    }

    temp = cardNameEditingController.text;

    onTapCardName(focusOfCardNameTextField.hasFocus);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //cardNameEditingController.text = widget.thisSpecificCardName;

    return (window.viewPadding.top > 0)
        ? SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 4 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                vertical: 1 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
              ),
              color: topContainerColor,
              child: Column(
                //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  //SizedBox(height: 12),

                  /// Back Arrow and More Options
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                      /// Back Arrow
                      backAndCrossWidget,

                      /// More Options
                      moreOptionsAndCheckWidget,
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 22),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        //width: 60 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                        child: TextField(
                          maxLines: null,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          onSubmitted: (value) {
                            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                            String temp = getCardName().toString();
                            if (temp.isNotEmpty) {
                              Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).setName(temp);
                              DatabaseServiceBoards().renameCardName(
                                widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                                widget.thisSpecificListName,
                                widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                                temp,
                              );
                              cardName = temp;
                              hintTextVar = temp;
                              cardNameEditingController.text = temp;
                              //Navigator.pop(context);
                            }
                            print(
                                'xxx Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).name 
${Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).cardsName}');

                            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                              currentFocus.unfocus();
                            }
                          },
                          focusNode: focusOfCardNameTextField,
                          controller: cardNameEditingController,
                          style: kMainPageHeaderStyle,
                          //keyboardType: inputType,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            isDense: true,
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            hintMaxLines: 20,
                            hintText: hintTextVar,
                            hintStyle: AppTheme.appBarPrimaryTextStyle,
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: 'KumbhSans',
                              fontSize: 2.3 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                            ),
                            suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontFamily: 'KumbhSans',
                              fontSize: 2.3 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                            ),
                          ),
                          //textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 12),
                      Text(
                        'List: ${widget.thisSpecificListName}' ?? 'Card of a List',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontFamily: 'KumbhSans'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 12),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 4 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
              vertical: 1 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
            ),
            color: topContainerColor,
            child: Column(
              //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                //SizedBox(height: 12),

                /// Back Arrow and More Options
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    /// Back Arrow
                    backAndCrossWidget,

                    /// More Options
                    moreOptionsAndCheckWidget,
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 22),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      //width: 60 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
                      child: TextField(
                        maxLines: null,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        onSubmitted: (value) {
                          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                          String temp = getCardName().toString();
                          if (temp.isNotEmpty) {
                            Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).setName(temp);
                            DatabaseServiceBoards().renameCardName(
                              widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                              widget.thisSpecificListName,
                              widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                              temp,
                            );
                            cardName = temp;
                            hintTextVar = temp;
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          }
                          cardNameEditingController.clear();
                          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                            currentFocus.unfocus();
                          }
                        },
                        focusNode: focusOfCardNameTextField,
                        controller: cardNameEditingController,
                        style: kMainPageHeaderStyle,
                        //keyboardType: inputType,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          hintMaxLines: 20,
                          hintText: hintTextVar,
                          hintStyle: AppTheme.appBarPrimaryTextStyle,
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'KumbhSans',
                            fontSize: 2.3 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                          ),
                          suffixStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontFamily: 'KumbhSans',
                            fontSize: 2.3 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                          ),
                        ),
                        //textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 12),
                    Text(
                      'List: ${widget.thisSpecificListName}' ?? 'Card of a List',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontFamily: 'KumbhSans'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 12),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  void onTapCardName(focus) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(
        () {
          if (focus == false) {
            FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            String temp = getCardName().toString();
            if (temp.isNotEmpty) {
              Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).setName(temp);
              DatabaseServiceBoards().renameCardName(
                widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                widget.thisSpecificListName,
                widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                temp,
              );
              //cardName = temp;
              //Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
              currentFocus.unfocus();
            }
            backAndCrossWidget = EditListCardBackIcon();
            moreOptionsAndCheckWidget = EditListCardMoreOptions(
              thisSpecificCardName: widget.thisSpecificCardName,
              thisSpecificListName: widget.thisSpecificListName,
              thisSpecificBoardName: widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
            );
          } else if (focus == true) {
            backAndCrossWidget = TopBarIcon(
              icon: Icons.clear,
              onPressedFunction: () {
                FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

                if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
                  currentFocus.unfocus();
                }

                cardNameEditingController.text = widget.thisSpecificCardName;
              },
            );
            moreOptionsAndCheckWidget = TopBarIcon(
              icon: Icons.check,
              onPressedFunction: () {
                FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                currentFocus.unfocus();
                String temp = getCardName().toString();
                if (temp.isNotEmpty) {
                  Provider.of<RenamedCard>(context, listen: false).setName(temp);
                  DatabaseServiceBoards().renameCardName(
                    widget.thisSpecificBoardName,
                    widget.thisSpecificListName,
                    widget.thisSpecificCardName,
                    temp,
                  );
                  cardName = temp;
                  hintTextVar = temp;
                  //Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
  }
}

final TextEditingController cardNameEditingController = TextEditingController();
var temp;

FocusNode focusOfCardNameTextField = FocusNode();



Future<void> renameCardName(thisSpecificBoardName, thisSpecificListName, thisSpecificCardName, 
newCardName) async {
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot = await collectionReference
        .doc(thisSpecificBoardName)
        .collection('lists')
        .doc(thisSpecificListName)
        .collection('cards')
        .doc(thisSpecificCardName)
        .get();

    print('xxx database card data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');

    if (thisSpecificCardName != newCardName) {
      await collectionReference
          .doc(thisSpecificBoardName)
          .collection('lists')
          .doc(thisSpecificListName)
          .collection('cards')
          .doc(thisSpecificCardName)
          .delete();
    }

    await collectionReference
        .doc(thisSpecificBoardName)
        .collection('lists')
        .doc(thisSpecificListName)
        .collection('cards')
        .doc(newCardName)
        .set(documentSnapshot.data());
  }
```